# haproxy pods in keep crashloopbackoff

Tags: haproxy, redis, helm

I'm using helm to install a redis-ha in my cluster with command: 
***helm install -f develop-redis-values.yaml stable/redis-ha --namespace=develop -n=develop-redis***

In develop-redis-values.yaml, i turn *haproxy.enabled* to *true*

When the pods appear, its state keep in CrashLoopBackOff.
The logs are:
[ALERT] 268/083933 (1) : parsing [/usr/local/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg:34] : 'tcp-check expect string' expects  as an argument.
[ALERT] 268/083933 (1) : Error(s) found in configuration file : /usr/local/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg
[ALERT] 268/083933 (1) : Fatal errors found in configuration.

Any one has the same issues or can fix it?